# CSS Selector QUERY

Tags: css

I have just started learning css

i have a nav in which i have five link tags the last tag has 3 link tags of its own .

i have given the last tag a class name .more

now when i am applying styling to those links under the last tag they are not working.

kindly somebody help in this i am pasting code below.

HTML -

```
<nav>
        <a href="">Tech</a>
        <a href="">PcS</a>
        <a href="">Phones</a>
        <a href="">Buying Guide</a>
        <a href="" class="more">

            <p>More</p>
            <a href="">ab</a>
            <a href=""><BC/a>
            <a href="">CD</a>
            <a href="">EF</a>


        </a>
    </nav>
```

css

```
nav {
        background: #3c2f2f;
        grid-column: 1/-1;
        grid-row: 2/3;
        /* space  */
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    nav a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .more {
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background: gray;
        display: flex;
    }

    nav .more > a {
        color: blue;

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem here. its working well

Comment: the links in .more class are not changing their color to blue

Comment: your code is wrong.. a inside a is not a format in html.. so you should change li inside a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code, and your statement '*i have given the last tag a class name .more*':

```
<a href="" class="more">
    <p>More</p>
    <a href="">ab</a>
    <a href="">BC</a>
    <a href="">CD</a>
    <a href="">EF</a>
</a>
```

You are using embedded `a` elements.  This is *not permitted* as per the W3C spec:

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.

The browser is likely to try to correct for the badly formatted HTML by creating each `A` as a non-nested element, which is breaking your CSS selector.

In order to achieve what you are looking to do, create a container element (like a `div`) under which the `more` class would apply:

```
<div class="more">
    <a href="">ab</a>
    <a href="">BC</a>
    <a href="">CD</a>
    <a href="">EF</a>
</div>
```

Your CSS selector `.more` and `nav .more > a` would then both work.

Ref: [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) (Nested links are illegal)

Comment: <a href="" class="more">

KINDLY CHECK last a tag in nav

Comment: @DEVZQ See my update reflecting the issue with embedded `a` elements

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is not a correct way to add **class** attribute, and you have to warp child elements in parent element to select element inside class

**Way to add class attribute**

```
<div class="more">....</div>
```

```css
nav {
        background: #3c2f2f;
        grid-column: 1/-1;
        grid-row: 2/3;
        /* space  */
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    nav a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .more {
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background: gray;
        display: flex;
    }

    nav .more > a {
        color: blue;

    }
```

```html
<nav>
        <a href="">Tech</a>
        <a href="">PcS</a>
        <a href="">Phones</a>
        <a href="">Buying Guide</a>
        <a href="" class="more"></a>
            <!--div warping a tag-->
            <div class="more">
            <a href="">ab</a>
            <a href="">BC</a>
            <a href="">CD</a>
            <a href="">EF</a>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: have a look at this line `<a href=""><BC/a>` you should have corrected it.

Comment: I did noticed it before but forgot to change thanks for feedback